# Return function and useState from customhook

Tags: reactjs, function, google-cloud-firestore, react-custom-hooks

I have a file uploader for firebase and it works wonderfully, except for the last thing. I have the function inside a custom hook and when applied it works, however I would like to return the status of progress ( either complete or error ) yet the only way I can seem to pass back the useState is by using a useEffect, which then causes other issues.

I have the custom hook operate with an onClick, to track the status I am using a useState which gets changed depending on the outcome.

However I can't return the function and the useState..

```
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage"
import { proStorage } from "../firebase/config"
import { v4 } from "uuid"
import { useState } from "react"

const useUploader = (data, foldername) => {
  const [upLoadcomplete, setuploacomplete] = useState()
  const uploadFiles = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const name = `$${v4()}`
      const location = `${foldername}/${name}`
      const metadata = {
        customMetadata: {
          uuid_name: name,
        },
      }
      const dataRef = ref(proStorage, location)
      const uploadtask = uploadBytesResumable(dataRef, data[i], metadata)
      console.log(uploadtask.metadata)

      uploadtask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done")
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case "paused":
              console.log("Upload is paused")
              break
            case "running":
              console.log("Upload is running")
              break
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          setuploacomplete("Error with upload try again")
        }
      )
    }
    setuploacomplete("Upload is now complete")
  }

  return uploadFiles
}
export default useUploader
```

I was following this for awhile but I am doing multipule files and the video is abit outdated with the newer ways of doing things.

I am hoping for some help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object in your custom hook to return the method and the `useState`.

Example:

```
import...

const useUploader = (data, foldername) => {
  const [upLoadcomplete, setuploacomplete] = useState()

  const uploadFiles = async () => {
    // ...
  }

  return {
    uploadFiles,
    upLoadcomplete,
  }
}
```

Then, you can use the custom hook like this:

```
const { uploadFiles, upLoadcomplete } = useUploader(data, foldername)

// Upload the files
uploadFiles()

// Check the status of the upload
if (upLoadcomplete === "Upload is now complete") {
  // ...
} else if (upLoadcomplete === "Error with upload try again") {
  // ...
}
```

This approach provides the following benefits:

- It is more effective because you don't have to repeatedly invoke the `useUploader` hook to obtain the function and the `useState`.
- You can easily see what the custom hook is returning, making it easier to read.
- You can return any kind of data from the custom hook instead of just a function, making it more flexible.